# Error creating control in asp.net and ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i have asp.net project in .net 2008 . for each aspx page contains ajax control UpdateProgress
but there is error (Error Creating Control ) although the library of ajax is in my project 
the library version is 1.0

Comment: http://im31.gulfup.com/4gnNa.jpg this is error image

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like the one control that's referenced probably because it doesn't have any explicit design-time support.  If that is your control, you can do things like:

```
if (this.DesignMode == true) {
  //Initialize some things so there aren't errors
}
```

It shouldn't be a problem at runtime though.

Comment: there is no error when run the project . the Problem . when i need to edit some controls in the page > this error not allow me to do any thins in desing page >

Comment: Right, but you are in the design mode, and if these are your components, you may need a custom designer, or to use the design mode attribute to control the rendering.

Comment: please can give me an example of design mode attribute  . the place >beacuse the Design Mode Property in Server code is bool value >cant change the our assign value to it

Comment: I meant property.  You're not supposed to assign to it; it's true in designmode, false at runtime.  Use it to render special HTML, instead of your normal rendering mode.  The reason they include is is HTTP and other services are not available, and your controls can error.  Or look at a custom control designer.